# Prepend custom code to an AWS Amplify resolver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I just started trying Amplify. Apparently, to do backend input validation, you're supposed to create a custom resolver such as `backend/api/projectname/resolvers/mutation.createTodo.req.vtl`. Then, I put the following inside:

```
#if( $ctx.args.input.name.length() > 10 )
    $util.error("Value for input field `CreateTodoInput.name` cannot exceed 10 characters.")
#end
```

If the input length is greater than 10 characters, then I get the error message as expected. However, if the input is less than 10 characters, I get `Template transformation yielded an empty response.`.

I'm assuming this is because I replaced the entire resolver instead of prepending to it. How can I prepend my custom validation to the resolver that Amplify auto-generates?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on generated resolver, and then modify it from there.

the generated resolver will be at `amplify/backend/api/projectname/build/resolvers`

Then copy it to the file you mentioned in the question, and modify it accordingly

This [article](https://www.fullsapps.com/2019/03/aws-amplify-overriding-auto-generated.html) has more details on how to override the resolver.

You can keep most of the logic, and just add your code on it.